# How to block Lookback Videos from Facebook newsfeed

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-lookback

How do I block the hundreds of Facebook Lookback videos being shared on my timeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**Social Fixer**](http://socialfixer.com/) browser extension's filter feature. Once Social Fixer is installed, go to the Social Fixer settings (blue wrench icon) <sub>[image: Social Fixer blue wrench icon]</sub> » Click on the Filtering tab » Enter a text string.

[image: Social Fixer filtering instructions]

[There are more detailed instructions on using the filter feature at this Social Fixer blog post here](http://socialfixer.com/blog/2012/08/17/sick-of-politics-on-facebook-social-fixer-can-fix-it/).